# Windows service - starting code not working if in shared library

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created multiple windows service and in each one i use following construct to maintain my service or debug it while testing.

Extracting this code to a shared library `dll` with class `WinServiceBase` and calling `WinServiceBase.StartOrInstallService(args, mainLogic, minutes)` it is not working.

Service seems to "start" *as it is shown in windows service panel* but nothing happens, no logging happens.

**Service**

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IMainLogic mainLogic = new MainLogic();
        int minutes = 120;

        // WinServiceBase.StartOrInstallService(args, mainLogic, minutes);

        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                mainLogic.Start();
                // timeout for debugging
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes));

                mainLogic.Pause();
            }
            else if (args.Length == 1)
            {
                switch (args[0])
                {
                    case "-install":
                        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location });
                        break;
                    case "-uninstall":
                        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location });
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            log.InfoFormat("Service: start...");
            ServiceBase.Run(WinServiceBase.GetInstance(mainLogic));
        }
    }
```

**Shared class library**

*ServiceBase is just a wrapper around the interface IMainLogic to start a service, reading its name from `app.config` and providing the static method based on above main method.*

```
public class WinServiceBase : ServiceBase 
{
    public static StartOrInstallService(String[] args, IMainLogic mainLogic, int minutes)
    {
        // same code as above main
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the same code from a service (the runtime environment you are targeting) and a console application (to make debugging the same code much easier)?  Is that what the goal is?

Comment: You have no `else` at the bottom of main, is that intentional?

Comment: @Will yes thats the goal. It works with no problems. I just want to refactor the `main` body into the static function. @Scott - no just a typo

Comment: It's all weird.  You're mixing in installing services with executing your logic.  They should be separated.  I could add an answer to illustrate, but I don't know why you are doing the work you're doing in the console app.  It's weird, not intuitive to me.

Comment: What is weird? It is a self installing service. Just run the service `exe` with the command `-install` and it will install itself. While debugging with visual studio the `Environment.UserInteractive` is active. This is very easy to use. And the problem is not about installing, it is about starting the service.